# The odd number algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am practicing on some algorithm problems and I have faced a problem which I can't understand clearly.
The problem is a string with N natural numbers, I need to search in this string for K distinct and disjoint sequences, containing in total a number L of elements, so that there is an odd number of odd numbers among the L elements. I want calculate the largest sum that can be obtained with these L numbers.

Input:
8 3 5 <-- natural numbers N, K and L.

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 <--- N natural numbers representing the numbers in the string

Subsequent {2}, {4}, {6,7,8} have an odd number of odd elements (one odd element, 7), their sum is 27 and is the maximum that can be obtained with 5 numbers that meet the required property.

Output:

27 <--- a single number representing the maximum amount by applying the rules.

My question is, how did he obtain that output?

Comment: I cannot imagine that there is a clever way to compute it. It seems to me you need a brute force approach: Assemble all combinations of sequences that are allowed by your constraints, and select the largest sum.

Comment: The example given is wrong you can choose {3} , {5} , {6, 7,8} sum = 29

Comment: @WasimAhmad The example given is correct.

Comment: @Noah how? What condition my answer didn't satisfy?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Do you mean like this example? 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

Comment: @WasimAhmad Some people had solved it and no one complained about a wrong input or such thing. I actually came here to understand how did they obtain this output from that input.

Comment: @Noah you better "quote" the real question. Because you are definitely missing something in here.

Comment: @Noah you can edit your answer or post link to the question or post screenshot of the question.

Comment: Yes, geeksforgeeks.org/… constructs a tree of all possible solutions, and you can walk through and select the maximum. I would be very surprised if there is a simpler way to do it, but you never know...

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Does the example I just gave you is done using divide & conquer algorithm?

Comment: A divide & conquer algorithm recursively breaks down a problem into simpler subproblems, solves them, and combines the sub solutions to the total solution. In your case, I believe, you have simply to compute all solutions, and chose the maximum. This is brute force, and is of course only appropriate, if there is not a more clever algorithm.